# C++ function equivalent to Python set() function

Tags: c++, set

I was wondering if there's a library function in C that can do the same job as set() in Python.
My purpose of using it is to check the total number of unique character in a string.

Code in Python example:

```py
aString = "abbc"
print(len(set(aString)))
```

This code will output 3. Since the set of aString is {a,b,c}. Is there something similar I can use in C++?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "c++ set class"?

Answer (score 2):

> My purpose of using it is to **check the total number of unique character** in a string

Yes you can create a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) from the [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and then get the sets' size using `std::set::size()` member function as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
int main()
{
    std::string aString = "abbc";

    //create set from std::string
    std::set<char> mySet( aString.begin() , aString.end() );
    
    std::cout<< mySet.size();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/O83NMsiws).

Note in C++ there is also option for [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) so that you would write:

```
    //create unordered_set from std::string
    std::unordered_set<char> mySet( aString.begin() , aString.end() ); //note the unordered_set used here instead of set
```

Comment: This not equivalent of python's `set`. `set` is unordered in python. `std:: unordered_set` would be it's equivalent I guess. But I guess for OP's output they just need to know number of unique elems. I guess either of them is fine for them.

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes because in the question OP said: *"My purpose of using it is to **check the total number of unique character in a string**"* .Also changing `std::set` to `std::unordered_set`(if needed) in my example is trivial.